# How to use netcdf in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, netcdf

I have two netcdf files (temperature, Humidity) and I would like to use them in a neural network to predict whether it will snow or not. The netcdfs have the format time* lat * lon*value I have a dataframe with the binary result (snow/no snow) for all times.

I have read the blog:
https://www.noahbrenowitz.com/post/loading_netcdfs/
on how to import netcdf in tensorflow but I am confused on how to use them as predictors in tensorflow with my response variable which will be a simple array.

Any idea?
if everything was in a dataframe it would look sth like (as features I created artificial data):

```
#Split data to test/train
labels=df['Snow']
features = df.iloc[:,2:10]
X=features
y=np.ravel(labels)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu', input_shape=(8,)))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
optimizer='sgd',
metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=8, batch_size=1, verbose=1)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,verbose=1)
```

Comment: This question really seems to made up of multiple questions. It sounds like you want to a) regrid the netCDF data to the observational data; b) convert that to a dataframe for use in tensforflow. Best to look up packages like xarray or my packag nctoolkit for how to do things like this

Comment: Thank you. What I am looking for is an example of building a neural network with netcdf as input. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I provide a response with what should have been useful information. Was it not useful?

Comment: Yes it is. But it would be nice to see an example - there are a lot online with mnist dataset for example but I cannot find any with netcdf.

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the netCDF data? You need to pre-process it, as I've said, for use by tensforflow. Please research how to do that

Comment: I do not think I need to re-grid it since it is in a fine resolution. I have made all the pre-preocessing (normalization etc). I want to use it as a predictor in the cnn. But I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Please read my original comment. Did I not tell you how to do that?

Comment: I used xarray and a generator to and I converted the netcdf to tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.MapDataset. From there I am lost.